# what other option in python keymap line for 'PRESS'?

Tags: python

I'm noob in this thing so I don't exactly know how to ask this.

so there is this line in a phyton script that responsible for setting key combination that will trigger the 'script', in this case is this one:

```
kmi = km.keymap_items.new(GPCRot.bl_idname, 'LEFTMOUSE', 'PRESS', ctrl=True, shift=False, alt=True)
```

so the script run when I press ctrl+alt+lmb, so from there I understand that the 'press' on the line above is responsible for the click behaviour. So is it possible to have other type of click('press'), like for example adding hold function so that the script would continue to run until I release the key?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Enum as below:

```
value (enum in ['ANY', 'NOTHING', 'PRESS', 'RELEASE', 'CLICK', 'DOUBLE_CLICK', 'CLICK_DRAG', 'NORTH', 'NORTH_EAST', 'EAST', 'SOUTH_EAST', 'SOUTH', 'SOUTH_WEST', 'WEST', 'NORTH_WEST'])
```

You can find the reference here: [KeyMapItens](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.KeyMapItems.html#bpy.types.KeyMapItems)

If you want to simulate holdup method, use the `'PRESS'` and `'RELEASE'` with `if` stament. Or maybe `'CLICK_DRAG'`